# Make AsyncLocal changes propagate to the calling function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, configureawait

DotNet Fiddle link https://dotnetfiddle.net/GqA32R

I have the following sample code to demonstrate the async local functionality

```
static AsyncLocal<string> _asyncLocalString = new AsyncLocal<string>();
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        // _asyncLocalString.Value = "Value 1";
        var t1 = AsyncMethodA();
        var t2 = AsyncMethodB();
        await Task.WhenAny(t1, t2).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.WriteLine("Async local inside Main: " + _asyncLocalString.Value); // null
    }

    static async Task AsyncMethodA()
    {
        // _asyncLocalString.Value = "Value 2";
        Console.WriteLine("Method A");
        Console.WriteLine("Async local inside A: " + _asyncLocalString.Value); // null
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }

static async Task AsyncMethodB()
    {
        _asyncLocalString.Value = "Value 3";
        Console.WriteLine("Method B");
        await AsyncMethodC().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    static async Task AsyncMethodC()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("Method C");
        Console.WriteLine("Async local inside C: " + _asyncLocalString.Value); // Value 3 is printed
    }
```

Output:

```
Method B
Method C
Async local inside C: Value 3
Method A
Async local inside A: 
Finished
Async local inside Main:
```

Is there a way to propogate these changes up the call stack so that async local changes in B are visible in A and main?

My real world scenario is similar to what I have above - the asyncLocal is set only in methodB and we have a few statements up the call stack which logs that value differently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to propogate these changes up the call stack so that async local changes in B are visible in A and main?

No, not with `AsyncLocal<T>`. [`async` methods set their value context to "copy-on-write"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html), so if it's written to, a copy will be created. And the copies never "flow" upwards.

You will need to use some other mechanism to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Any idea about what that "other mechanism" might be? I thought about something like a static global mapping of Thread.ManagedThreadId  to the corresponding value, but the ManagedThreadId doesn't have to stay the same across an async program flow... so I fail to find an identifier for the current ExecutionContext which could be used.

Comment: @BudBrot: One approach is to make the `T` mutable (or having a mutable member), but I generally discourage that. Another approach is to create a unique identifier and have a global mapping of some kind from those to your values.

Comment: @BudBrot just create some container class like this: `class Container<T> { public T ContainedValue {get; set;} }` and then use it like this: `AsyncLocal<Container<string>>`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to propogate these changes up the call stack so that async local changes in B are visible in A and main?

You could wrap the instance for example with `AsyncLocal<StrongBox<T>>`.
In this way the value will live inside the instance originally set by the parent.